# How to use "Replace" in matrix?

Tags: matrix, replacement, output

I would like to change the form of matrix output, for example:

```
A = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}};
B = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};
B.A
```

This will give me a matrix that is the same as the value of `B`, namely `{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}`. How can I let the output be `B` (literally)?

I had tried `Replace[B.A, B.A -> B]`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `A . B = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}` ? Please edit the question further. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: `Replace[B . A, Dot[B, A] -> B]` ?

Comment: Thank you~But it seems not to work.

Comment: Please include the expected output to your post.

Comment: Yes, just I said, I want to let the output be "B", not "{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}", since I had defined they are equivalent.

Comment: `Replace[B . A, Dot[B, A] -> HoldForm[B]]` ? Since you have defined a value for `B`, every time it appears without a hold of some type, it will be evaluated to `{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}`.

Comment: You are right~ thank you, Syed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `B` is found in the result you can replace it by `Defer[B]`:

```
A = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}};
B = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};
B.A /. {A -> Defer[A], B -> Defer[B]}
(* B *)
```